# Convert Excel range to HTML - SheetJS

Tags: javascript, sheetjs, js-xlsx

I am trying to generate a HTML table from a specified range of an Excel worksheet, but not the entire sheet using `sheetJS`

SheetJS has the function, `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(ws, opts)`, that will convert the sheet to HTML, and maintains merged cells, etc, which is great, but not sure how to limit the range converted. For example, I have a worksheet with two ranges:

- A1:C5
- E6:G10

I want to create a HTML table from the values within the E6:G10, and ignore the A1:C5. The E6 and E7 are merged. Do I need to first move the E6:G10 range to a new worksheet, and then use `sheet_to_html()` to create the HTML table? If so, what's the best approach, unless there is a built-in method?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, it is not possible to limit it that way. You have to copy your desired range to new worksheet variable and then apply `sheet_to_html()` to get what you want